# Wix MSI installer put garbage character in sql script

Tags: wix, sql-scripts

I have to create tables inside already existing database While I run my mis package it through error for garbage character which I trace out using sql profiler. How to solve this issue my code is following

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs"
     xmlns:util="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/util"
     xmlns:sql="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/sql"
     >
  <Product Id="*" Name="GAT.DATAC.Deployment.Database" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Gat" UpgradeCode="f5e8f09a-7df7-4699-9670-65f9f4003c58">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />


    <!--<util:User Id="SQLUser" Name="test" Password="ba" />-->
    <Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
      <Directory Id='ProgramFilesFolder' Name='PFiles'>
        <Directory Id='InstallDir' Name='Acme'>

          <Component Id='SqlComponent' Guid='8A1C82DB-1DD3-4FB5-8600-4F370FE1E04B' KeyPath='yes'>

            <sql:SqlDatabase Id="SqlDatabase" Database="dbGATAC" Server="PC4" CreateOnInstall="yes" DropOnUninstall="yes" ContinueOnError="no">
              <!--User="SQLUserSA"-->
              <sql:SqlScript Id='CreateTable' BinaryKey='CreateTablesBin' ExecuteOnInstall='yes' />
            </sql:SqlDatabase>
            <!--<sql:SqlScript Id="CreateTables" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" SqlDb="SqlDatabase.IntegratedAuthentication"  ExecuteOnUninstall="no" BinaryKey="CreateTablesBin" ContinueOnError="no" />-->
            <CreateFolder/>

          </Component>

        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>

    <Binary Id='CreateTablesBin' SourceFile='DatabaseSchema\SqlCreateDb.sql' />

    <Feature Id='SqlFeature' Title='SqlFeature' Level='1'>
      <ComponentRef Id='SqlComponent' />
    </Feature>

  </Product>
</Wix>

and while I run it display following script for execution in profiler

exec ï»¿CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Widgets] (
        [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
        [Configuration] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
        [Dashboard_Id] [uniqueidentifier],
        CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Widgets] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
    )
```

Now ï»¿ is inserted by wix installer and restricting my script to execute.

Comment: Just noticed that you seem to be using "nightly build" release of WIX (v4.x)? Is it on purpose, or by mistake? If by mistake, try the latest stable version (3.10.2)

Comment: Thank you nikolay for you text I have solved this issue I jst need to save this file as utf-8 without signature and it works and I want newer version so that is why used latest version

Comment: Okay, so that was UTF-8 BOM marker then. Good that the issue solved :)

Comment: @zaheerahmad You can write this as answer (and accept it). Also consider filing this as a bug in WiX (or at least the documentation).

Comment: Thank you @TomBlodget yes I am adding this as answer

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue after saving my file with utf-8 without signature and it works for me. It kind a bug in Wix.